# Current induced from a magnet moving through a solenoid?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-current, induction

If we had a magnet we move it towards a solenoid a half sine wave current is induced when we make it move back, the other half is induced, inducing an AC current in the solenoid.

What if the magnet moves towards the solenoid, inside it and comes the other side? Will a current be induced while the magnet is moving inside (not entering nor exiting the solenoid, given that length of solenoid is much bigger than that of the magnet).

If yes, what kind of current will be induced? If no, why?
If AC current is induced, how would one calculate its frequency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The magnet will induce a current in any loop through which it passes.  If the solenoid is a single piece of conductive material, a current induced in one loop will produce current throughout the whole thing.  This current is due to *changing* magnetic flux in the loop.  As the magnet enters a loop, it will produce a current, and as it exits a loop it will produce a current in the opposite direction.  As the magnet falls through the length of the long solenoid, as you describe, it is entering loops at the same rate it is exiting them - so, the net effect is zero current.

Comment: That is what i thought , but here's an idea,
 what if i connect to my loop a blocking diode , blocking current current in one way ( current induced while it's exiting a loop for example) will there be a net induced current?

Comment: Yes, I believe so.